# Linear programming multiplication step at the end for nothing?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

I'm new to linear programming and I found a basic example on simplex. It's about producing tablets and phones.
[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGzXd.png)

The equations are the following:

$$1P-7x1-5x2+0s1+0s2=0$$
$$0P+4x1+3x2+1s1+0s2=240$$
$$0p+2x1+1x2+0s1+1s2=100$$
after making the equations and solving them they are saying to multiply the last row by 2 as final step.
[penultimate tableau, where the blue numbers stand for the solution after the ERO operation that is indicated in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFmWe.png)

[final solution where they multiplied the last row with 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlsxz.png)

As far as I can follow I don't see why this would be usefull.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: okay didn't know, i'll adapt my first picture to this formula notation

Comment: I do not see why it is useful either.

Comment: Could it be something with that you can not make a half tablet/smartphone?